# Selenium2 WebDriver cannot find element in IE7, XP, Windows7

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I developed my test automation using IEDriverServer 2.25.0 and C# on my machine running XP, and IE7.  Everything works fine.  I created a setup package of my solution and deployed into another machine (Windows7, IE8), and the webdriver cannot find the elements on my tested webpage.

I installed Visual Studio and C# in another XP, IE7 machine.  When I run the code, it has the same problem as in the Windows7 machine.

I tried to set the protection mode to on/off on all zones, but it does not work either.

I'm wondering if there is any settings Firewall/Antivirus/etc... that is making the webdriver not able to find the web elements??

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you try a different Driver? (Chrome or Firefox) Wondering if the problem is specific to the IEDriver.

Comment: I did not try different driver as all my PageObjects where coded for IE.  I did try the newer IEDriverServer 2.25.3 and the problem persists.

Comment: It should not be impossible to change it from being an IEDriver to ChromeDriver.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.  My test machine should be in the same network as the webserver.  The IP Address of my webserver is 10.104.200.110 with mask 255.255.255.0.  Although my test machine can surf the webserver, it had a different IP address.  So I changed the IP to 10.104.200.100 with mask 255.255.255.0 and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with IE7, I mean I thought this is only IE7 issue since on IE6, IE8, IE9 the web page I have to test was working fine.
The web page has broken certificate (because this is R&D environment).
The soution was to add the page address to trusted sites.
I hope this helps someone, because I was looking everywhere and didn't find anything.
Now it seems obvious but nothing indicated that the problem was because of that, google page was working ok but the page I should test did not.